# I want to see the old buttons in my app in iOS 7

Tags: ios, xcode, button, ios7

I'm really newbie in iOS development and I have an app that was developed with Xcode 4.6 and was running in iOS 6.1 (https://itunes.apple.com/br/app/unipay/id670441051?mt=8), but after I download the new Xcode (few hours ago) and try to run in my iPhone, what happened is that the layout was completely broken, because the new iOS changed automatically the old buttons to the new iOS buttons:

[Take a look in "Login" and "Cancelar" (cancel) buttons bellow]

https://devforums.apple.com/servlet/JiveServlet/showImage/28931/foto.png

Other thing that happened is taht the phrase in top of this app was white, but now is black.

So, the question is: how to back the layout to the old layout, without the brand new of iOS 7? I need to do this now because I have some important issues that I need to fix and send to Apple Store before change the layout of my app (that my team already is developing a brand new design for that).

Thank you!

Comment: Your image link is broken, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your only option is to restyle the buttons to look like how they used to - if that is truly what you want the app to look like. The more logical solution is to redesign your app for the new iOS 7 look and feel just as Apple have done and other developers are doing.

Comment: That's a big problem for me now, because my new layout will delay a lot to be done, and then I'll have to apply in my app (and I'm really REALLY newbie in iOS development).. :(

Answer (score 3):

Build your app. against sdk 6.1. App. will keep working for iOS 7. and you still can publish this version to the apple store.

Comment: Apple are no longer accepting new app submissions or updates that do not compile against the 7 SDK.

Comment: My app is compatible is iOS 7, but I need to send just a fix of this app with the old layout of my navigationItem. It was (and is) working fine in iOS 7, but still with the old layout, but when I build in Xcode now, it's already in new layout of navigationItem. I can't upload to Apple with this new layout, can you understand? What should I do to build in last version of layout?

Comment: @Jasarien That's incorrect.  To quote an Apple rep: "it will probably be many, many months (if not longer) before" iOS 6 SDK apps will no longer be accepted.  They currently accept all GM releases of Xcode, all the way back to Xcode 3.  It's reasonable to expect that Xcode 4.6 will be supported for a very long time.